# Derrida and 'time is out of joint'

Tags: time, derrida

What is the deal with Derrida and the notion of time? Why is Derrida so obsessed with time and the famous phrase from Hamlet, "time is out of joint."?

I am reading Spectres of Marx, and am unable to understand what he's trying to say.

Can someone please elaborate on that?

Thanks

Comment: You can try with Joanna Hodge, [Derrida on Time](https://books.google.it/books?id=U6fJq11uqoQC&printsec=frontcover) (2007), but it seems to me that the reference to *Hamlet*'s phrase is mostly metaphorical.